# How to set up custom layout for spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, window

I want to ask something regarding making my own custom layout for spacemacs. I have read the documentation. They have an [example](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org#custom-layouts)  like this:

This is the custom layout for `ERC` buffers.

```
(spacemacs|define-custom-layout "@ERC"
  :binding "E"
  :body
  (progn
    ;; hook to add all ERC buffers to the layout
    (defun spacemacs-layouts/add-erc-buffer-to-persp ()
      (persp-add-buffer (current-buffer)
                        (persp-get-by-name
                        erc-spacemacs-layout-name)))
    (add-hook 'erc-mode-hook #'spacemacs-layouts/add-erc-buffer-to-persp)
    ;; Start ERC
    (call-interactively 'erc)))
```

Since I am still beginner is Emacs Lisp, I don't really know what is happening here.

Let say I have four files in my home directory:

1. `~/file1.org`
2. `~/file2.org`
3. `~/file3.org`
4. `~/file4.org`

I want them automatically to be opened like this in my spacemacs:

```
|-----------+-----------|
| file1.org | file2.org |
|           |           |
|           |           |
|-----------+-----------|
| file3.org | file4.org |
|           |           |
|           |           |
|-----------+-----------|
```

Can anyone show me how can I achieve this (I am hoping that it comes with explanation since I am trying to learn through implementation)? Or at least can anyone tell me some keywords or Elisp functions that I can try to google on?

If it helps, I do regularly program in Python. So, a quite simple explanation is maybe enough for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily save and load layouts in spacemacs:

- create your layout with `SPC l l`
- split and open the files you need, resize to taste etc.
- press `SPC l s`. Choose a name for your layout and confirm

Next time you open spacemacs just press `SPC l L` and choose your layout.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a few custom layout similar to this:

```
(spacemacs|define-custom-layout "My Python Layout"
  :binding "p"
  :body
  (find-file "*path to upper left file*")
  (split-window-right) ;; Create the right side but don't move focus
  (split-window-below-and-focus) ;; Split the left side into two and move focus
  (find-file "*path to lower left file*")
  (winum-select-window-3) ;; Go to the top right window
  (find-file "*path to upper right file*")
  (split-window-below-and-focus) ;; Split the right side into two and move focus
  (find-file "*path to lower right file*")
  (winum-select-window-1) ;; Move focus back to the first window (optional)
)
```